# It is safe to use $window.location.assign instead of $location.path()? | angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing a service in AngularJS and I want that service do a redirection on a page I choose. I don't have a $scope in this so I'm using:

```
$window.location.assign('path');
```

as [documented on w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp).

What I'm asking is if this is a safe usage or if I should use something different.

ps: those doesn't work:

```
$location.assign(); //assign is not a function
//
$location.path();
$scope.$apply(); //I don't have a $scope
```

Many thanks.

**EDIT:** added code (in `socketio.listen('auth.loggedInSuccessfully', function(data) {` I'm having the issue I described)

```
angular.module('frontendApp')
    .factory('login', function ($window, socketio, $rootScope) {
        // Service logic
        // ...
        var loginType = null;

        // prepare socketio events
        socketio.listen();

        socketio.listen('auth.loggedInSuccessfully', function(data) {
            console.log("Login verified by server!.. Redirecting...");
            console.log("Login data received: " + JSON.stringify(data));
            $rootScope.user = data.user;
            $rootScope.$apply();
            loginType = "facebook";
            //console.log("$rootScope.user: " + JSON.stringify($rootScope.user.name));
            //$location.path(destUrl); // THIS doesn't work.
            $window.location.assign(data.destUrl); // this does!
        });
        socketio.listen('auth.loginFailed', function() {
            console.log("Login failed!");
            $rootScope.user = {}
        });
        socketio.listen('auth.logout', function() {
            console.log("Logged out!");
            $rootScope.user = {};
        })

        // Public API here
        var api = {
            fb: {
                validateToken: function (access_token, destUrl) {
                    socketio.emit('fb.login', {
                        access_token: access_token,
                        destUrl: destUrl
                    });
                    console.log("Waiting server response...");
                },[...]
        };
        return api;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting your code.

I believe in your example the location change is taking place in an event handler outside of AngularJS.  Typically this requires the state changes to be wrapped in a $scope.$apply.  Perhaps something like this:

```
socketio.listen('auth.loggedInSuccessfully', function(data) {
    console.log("Login verified by server!.. Redirecting...");
    console.log("Login data received: " + JSON.stringify(data));
    loginType = "facebook";
    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
        $rootScope.user = data.user;
        $location.path(destUrl);
    });
});
```